# get header for the cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have this

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Row.Cells[0].Style.Add("text-align", "center");
    }
```

i want to make the header of this cell invisible.. how can i do this by just knowing the cell value...

it does not find the header... i am creating the header at runtime... like this

```
GridView Grid = new GridView();
Grid.RowDataBound += Grid_RowDataBound;


        Grid.ID = machGrps[j].ToString();
        //Grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        Grid.AllowSorting = false;
        Grid.CellSpacing = 2;
        Grid.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        Grid.GridLines = GridLines.None;
        Grid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        Grid.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Overflow, "Scroll");
        Grid.ShowHeader = true;

DataTable taskTable = new DataTable("TaskList7");
taskTable.Columns.Add("MachineID");

DataRow tableRow = taskTable.NewRow();
tableRow["MachineID"] = machID[i];
taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
Grid.DataSource = taskTable;
Grid.DataBind();

   protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to make the header of one cell invisible? Or all cells? I don't think it's possible to make one the headers invisible...

Comment: one header.. like header of cell[0] invisible

Comment: i can make the cell invisible by e.Row[0].Visible = false;

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for VB.Net :

```
Select Case e.Row.RowType
    Case DataControlRowType.Header
        e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False
End Select
```

**Edit**: C#

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header){
   e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False;
}
```

Comment: it is not able to  find the header of the row.. it does not execute the above statement

Comment: Do you have ShowHeader="true"? Show us the aspx markup of your grid.
Does your Grid contain rows?

Comment: as you can see above in my code i am making the grid on runtime.. so there is no HTML code. the header gets created when taskTable.Columns.Add("MachineID"); is executed and therows are created by the code below it.

Comment: I must repeat my question: have you set ShowHeader="true"? I wanted to see your aspx markup of the grid for example to see if you have registered GridView1_RowDataBound. Your code touches my DataControlRowType.Header in RowDataBound.

Comment: i have posted the edit of my code above. i also put the Grid.Show = true also but it din work....

Comment: i really appreciate all the help

Comment: Sorry, my bed is calling ;-)
A last try: where do you add the grid to the page? Good luck...